# Can I split a string in c# VB6-style without referencing Microsoft.VisualBasic?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

Unfortunately, there seems to be no string.Split(string separator), only string.Split(char speparator).

I want to break up my string based on a multi-character separator, a la VB6.  Is there an easy (that is, not by referencing Microsoft.VisualBasic or having to learn RegExes) way to do this in c#?

EDIT: Using .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String.Split()` has other overloads. Some of them take `string[]` arguments.

```
string original = "first;&second;&third";
string[] splitResults = original.Split( new string[] { ";&" }, StringSplitOptions.None );
```

Answer (score 1):

the regex for spliting string is extremely simple so i would go with that route.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Which version of .Net?  At least 2.0 onwards includes the following overloads:

```
.Split(string[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)  
.Split(string[] separator, int count, StringSplitOptions options)
```

Now if they'd only fix it to accept any IEnumerable<string> instead of just array.

Answer (score 0):

The regex version is probably prettier but this works too:

```
string[] y = { "bar" };

string x = "foobarfoo";
foreach (string s in x.Split(y, StringSplitOptions.None))
      Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This'll print foo twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"[stop]"};
    string[] result;
result = someString.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use this under .NET 2.0 all the time.

```
string[] args = "first;&second;&third".Split(";&".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```